# Words before rules are not divided

Tags: hyphenation

I just got an overfull hbox with an em rule at the
end of the rule and fixed the problem by inserting a kern between it
and the rule:
`collectively\kern0pt---`.  It seems that by default the
rule disables hyphenation for the word in front of it.  Is
there a reason for this?
Maybe TeX considers the rule part of the word, but shouldn't
this behaviour be changed?

Comment: From your question I am not sure what you are looking for.  A MWE would be a great help in clarifying.  _What makes a good MWE_ http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3343/90087

Comment: this answer should be useful: [Hyphenation problem with — versus \textemdash](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56658/579)

Answer (score 5):

TeX does not hyphenate words already containing the font's hyphen character, normally set to `-`, or ligatures ending with this character.

As far as hyphenation is concerned, TeX considers a *word* to be a run of characters in the same font, each one of category code 11 or 12.

Therefore `collectively---` is considered as a single word for hyphenation purposes, and, since it contains `-`, it is not subject to automatic hyphenation and is only breakable at the explicit hyphens in it (ligatures ending with the hyphenchar are considered as a single unit) or at explicit discretionary items.

This is desirable, because hyphenating such a combination should be a conscious decision, when nothing else is possible in order to get a good paragraph.

An explicit kern is not among the items considered to form a word, so with `collectively\kern0pt---` you have *two* words, separated by a kern. Then `collectively` is examined for automatic hyphenation.

In this particular case, the solution can be acceptable, because TeX hyphenates `collectively` as `col-lect-ively`, so you either get

> ......................................... col-
>    lectively—

or

> ......................................... collect-
>    ively—

but in other cases the hyphen might fall very near to the end of the word.

I'd prefer leaving the decision for the final stage. If you finally opt for hyphenating, type in

```
col\-lectively---
```

Comment: Would the result be different if there was also a kern was between two characters, eg: `col \kern 1pt lectively\kern 0pt ----` ?

Comment: @AFeldman You wouldn't get a hyphen

Comment: So the `\kern` would prevent it from being recognized as a word on the hyphenation list, because with the kern being in place TeX sees the words "col" and "lectively" separated by the kern.

Comment: Interesting preference.  So normally you'd prefer the last
break point but here you prefer the first?  Because you don't 
like 'ively---' at the beginning of a line?  I prefer the 
last break point in both cases.

Comment: @Lawrence It's indeed a question of personal preference; I feel that short word fragments in the next line are unclear in such a context. But my preference would definitely go to non hyphenating.

Comment: Given your statement, "TeX considers a word to be a run of characters in the same font, each one of category code 11 or 12", how is it that diacritics are handled to still be considered part of "a word".  I understand that diacritical letters are still letters, but from the TeX view, what differentiates a diacritic macro like `\"` from any other macro?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes In the T1 encoding, `\"u` is transformed into a single character. It isn't in OT1 and, indeed, words containing a built up accent are only hyphenatable before the accented letter. See my answer to [`fontenc` vs `inputenc`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/)

Comment: Then why, in the case of `\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\textwidth=1.1in\sloppy
\begin{document}
\ae sthetic \ae sthetic 
\end{document}`, does aesthetic hyphenate, with no (i.e., commented) `T1` encoding?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\ae` points to a single character

Comment: Thank you.  So there is no way to make a word like, for example, `emph\mbox{a}tically` hyphenate, even by various invocations of `\hyphenation` on its fragments? or with `\lccode` invocations, etc?  If you would like, I can ask this as a question?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No, only the word fragments; but if you want hyphenation in `tically`, you need `emph\mbox{a}\nobreak\hspace{0pt}tically`, because hyphenation is also abandoned if a run of characters isn't preceded by a skip.