# Altering a lualatex code to apply \smash to letters with descenders and math automatically

Tags: math-mode, formatting, luatex, letters, lua

I am studying the solution provided in this Stack Exchange thread: [Is there a way to automatically smash all inline maths (but only vertically)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643331/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-smash-all-inline-maths-but-only-vertically/643339), which was originally answered by user Mico. I've included the relevant code from Mico's answer below. This code applies \smash to everything within the $$ (inline math) environment. However, I am interested in extending this functionality to also apply \smash to not only math, but also any letters in the main text with descenders, such as 'p', 'q', 'y,' and others.

As I discussed with Mico, it appears to be more challenging than initially expected to implement this additional functionality. If you have any suggestions or alternative approaches to achieve the desired effect, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you for your help!

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\dfrac' macro
\usepackage{lipsum}   % filler text
\usepackage{luacode}  % for 'luacode' env.
\begin{luacode}
   function smash ( s )
     return ( s:gsub ( "%b$$" , "\\smash{%1}" ) )
   end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\SmashOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
   "process_input_buffer", smash, "smash" )}}
\newcommand\SmashOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback (
   "process_input_buffer", "smash" )}}
  
\begin{document} 
\hrule % draw line to illustrate width of textblock
\lipsum[1][1-5] $\dfrac{\dfrac{v}{v}}{\dfrac{w}{x}}$ \lipsum[1][5-8]
\hrule
\SmashOn % activate the Lua function
\lipsum[1][1-5] $\dfrac{\dfrac{v}{v}}{\dfrac{w}{x}}$ \lipsum[1][5-8]
\hrule
\SmashOff % deactivate the Lua function 
\lipsum[1][1-5] $\dfrac{\dfrac{v}{v}}{\dfrac{w}{x}}$ \lipsum[1][5-8]
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you just want to preserve line spacing, you do not need `\smash` at all, just set `\lineskiplimit` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524976/fontspec-how-to-keep-baselineskip-stable/524980#524980 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549218/what-is-the-behaviour-of-fontsize-if-baselineskip-is-below-a-certain-value/549219#549219

Comment: I'm really looking to see if my exact request is possible.

Comment: Could you please provide the completed code to get this to work? I'd like to avoid long comment sections

Comment: Can you provide a MWE that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a pretty bad idea to me—usually you want the descenders to have depth so that they don't collide with other characters. Nevertheless, it's not *too* tricky to do this automatically with Lua:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

%% The next section contains the code that is necessary to automatically smash
%% descenders in math and text modes.
%%% BEGIN REQUIRED CODE %%%
\newif\ifautosmash

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
    local iftrue = token.create("iftrue").mode

    -- Handle descenders in text mode
    local function smash_nodes(head)
        -- Check to see if autosmashing is enabled
        if token.create("ifautosmash").mode ~= iftrue then
            return head
        end

        -- Iterate over all nodes in the list
        local n = head
        repeat
            -- Remove descenders
            if n.id == node.id("glyph") then
                local new = node.copy_list(n, n.next)

                -- We can't modify the depth of a glyph directly, so we
                -- need to pack it into a box.
                local box = node.hpack(new)
                box.depth = 0

                -- Replace the glyph
                head, box = node.insert_after(head, n, box)
                head = node.remove(head, n)

                n = node.free(n)
            end
            n = n.next
        until not n

        return head
    end

    luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter", smash_nodes, "smash_nodes")
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("hpack_filter", smash_nodes, "smash_nodes")


    -- Handle descenders in math mode
    local function smash_math(...)
        local n = node.mlist_to_hlist(...)

        if token.create("ifautosmash").mode == iftrue then
            n = node.hpack(n)
            n.depth = 0
        end

        return n
    end

    luatexbase.add_to_callback("mlist_to_hlist", smash_math, "smash_math")
\end{luacode*}
%%% END REQUIRED CODE %%%


%% The following code is just to draw a box around its contents; it is
%% *not* necessary for the rest of the code to work.
%%% BEGIN EXTRA CODE %%%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_const:Nn \c__max_thickness_dim { 0.1pt }
\dim_new:N \g__max_half_ex_dim
\dim_new:N \l__max_asc_ht_dim
\dim_new:N \l__max_des_dp_dim
\box_new:N \l__max_contents_box
\box_new:N \l__max_hline_box
\box_new:N \l__max_vline_box

\cs_new:Nn \__max_font_size: {
    \fontsize { 0.2em } { 0.2em } \selectfont \scshape
}

\cs_new:Nn \__max_hline:nn {
    \box_move_up:nn { #2 - \g__max_half_ex_dim } {
        \hbox_overlap_left:n {
            \__max_font_size: #1
            \skip_horizontal:n {
                \g__max_half_ex_dim + (\c__max_thickness_dim / 2)
            }
        }
    }

    \box_move_up:nn { #2 } { \box_use:N \l__max_hline_box }

    \box_move_up:nn { #2 - \g__max_half_ex_dim } {
        \hbox_overlap_right:n {
            \skip_horizontal:n {
                \box_wd:N \l__max_contents_box +
                \g__max_half_ex_dim +
                (\c__max_thickness_dim / 2)
            }
            \__max_font_size: #1
        }
    }
}

\cs_new:Nn \__max_vline:n {
    \hbox_set_to_wd:Nnn \l_tmpa_box { 0pt } { \hss \__max_font_size: #1 \hss }

    \box_move_down:nn {
        \box_dp:N \l__max_contents_box +
        \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box +
        \g__max_half_ex_dim +
        (\c__max_thickness_dim / 2)
    } {
        \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
    }

    \box_move_up:nn {
        \box_ht:N \l__max_contents_box +
        \box_dp:N \l_tmpa_box +
        \g__max_half_ex_dim +
        (\c__max_thickness_dim / 2)
    } {
        \box_use_drop:N \l_tmpa_box
    }

    \box_use:N \l__max_vline_box
}

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \__max_dimcomp:nn { T } {
    \bool_if:nTF {
        \dim_compare_p:n {
            #1 < 0.8 #2
        }
        ||
        \dim_compare_p:n {
            #1 > 1.2 #2
        }
    } {
        \prg_return_true:
    } {
        \prg_return_false:
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \drawbox } { m } {
    \group_begin:
        \__max_font_size:
        \dim_gset:Nn \g__max_half_ex_dim { 0.5ex }
    \group_end:

    \hbox_set:Nn \l__max_contents_box { \color_ensure_current: #1 }

    \hbox_set_to_wd:Nnn \l__max_hline_box { 0pt } {
        \vrule
            width \box_wd:N \l__max_contents_box height \c__max_thickness_dim
            height 0.5 \c__max_thickness_dim
            depth 0.5 \c__max_thickness_dim
        \hss
    }

    \hbox_set_to_wd:Nnn \l__max_vline_box { 0pt } {
        \hss
        \vrule
            width \c__max_thickness_dim
            height \dim_eval:n {
                \box_ht:N \l__max_contents_box + (\c__max_thickness_dim / 2)
            }
            depth \dim_eval:n {
                \box_dp:N \l__max_contents_box + (\c__max_thickness_dim / 2)
            }
        \hss
    }

    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { l h t i }
    \dim_set:Nn \l__max_asc_ht_dim { \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box }

    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { y j p g }
    \dim_set:Nn \l__max_des_dp_dim { \box_dp:N \l_tmpa_box }

    \hbox:n {
        \color_group_begin:
            \color_select:n { red ! 50 ! black ! 75 ! white }

            \__max_hline:nn { bl } { 0pt }
            \__max_hline:nn { ht } { \box_ht:N \l__max_contents_box }
            \__max_hline:nn { ex } { 1ex }

            \__max_hline:nn {
                \__max_dimcomp:nnT {
                    0pt
                } {
                    \box_dp:N \l__max_contents_box
                } {
                    dp
                }
            } { - \box_dp:N \l__max_contents_box }

            \__max_hline:nn {
                \__max_dimcomp:nnT {
                    \l__max_asc_ht_dim
                } {
                    \box_ht:N \l__max_contents_box
                } {
                    asc
                }
            } { \l__max_asc_ht_dim }

            \__max_hline:nn {
                \__max_dimcomp:nnT {
                    \l__max_des_dp_dim
                } {
                    \box_dp:N \l__max_contents_box
                } {
                    des
                }
            } { -\l__max_des_dp_dim }

            \__max_vline:n { l }

            \hbox_overlap_right:n {
                \skip_horizontal:n { \box_wd:N \l__max_contents_box }
                \__max_vline:n { r }
            }
        \color_group_end:

        \box_use_drop:N \l__max_contents_box
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%% END EXTRA CODE %%%


%% Example usage and demonstration
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
        \autosmashfalse \drawbox{glyph glyph glyph} &
        \autosmashtrue  \drawbox{glyph glyph glyph} \\

        \autosmashfalse \drawbox{glyph $\displaystyle\int$ glyph} &
        \autosmashtrue  \drawbox{glyph $\displaystyle\int$ glyph} \\

        \autosmashfalse \drawbox{glyph $\sqrt{x}^2$ glyph} &
        \autosmashtrue  \drawbox{glyph $\sqrt{x}^2$ glyph} \\

        \autosmashfalse \drawbox{glyph $q_{g_{y_{p_j}}}$ glyph} &
        \autosmashtrue  \drawbox{glyph $q_{g_{y_{p_j}}}$ glyph} \\

        \multicolumn{2}{p{2.3in}}{
            \fontsize{8pt}{0pt}\selectfont \autosmashtrue

            The image on top displays how the descenders are automatically
            smashed when \texttt{\char`\\ auto\-smash\-true} is running.
            Collisions are quite frequent, so be very careful with low-hanging
            equations like $\sqrt{x_1} = \int_0^1 \beta_y$. Notice that only the
            depth is tighter---the line above is lowered by \LaTeX{} to account
            for its extra height.
        }
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

You can see in the comparison table that the depth is completely removed whenever you toggle on `\autosmashtrue`, without affecting the height, width, or positioning. This looks alright in the table, but in the body text demo that follows it looks pretty bad.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to modify individual descender glyph boxes to avoid that they affect the line spacing, the feature is already built in to classic TeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\dfrac' macro
\usepackage{lipsum}   % filler text
\def\SmashOn{\par\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen}
\def\SmashOff{\par\lineskiplimit= \normallineskiplimit}
\begin{document} 
\hrule % draw line to illustrate width of textblock
\lipsum[1][1-5] $\dfrac{\dfrac{v}{v}}{\dfrac{w}{x}}$ \lipsum[1][5-8]
\hrule
\SmashOn % activate the Lua function
\lipsum[1][1-5] $\dfrac{\dfrac{v}{v}}{\dfrac{w}{x}}$ \lipsum[1][5-8]
\hrule
\SmashOff % deactivate the Lua function 
\lipsum[1][1-5] $\dfrac{\dfrac{v}{v}}{\dfrac{w}{x}}$ \lipsum[1][5-8]
\hrule
\end{document}
```